# Binding index in template Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need a counter starting with 2. 
How to link [mdDatepicker], [mdDatepickerToggle], #next_payment_?

```html
<div formArrayName="next_payment">
  <div *ngFor="let payment of productForm.controls.next_payment.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span>Payment {{i + 2}}</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="productForm.controls.next_payment.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeNextPayment(i)"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="'next_payment' + i + 2" [ngModel]="npd | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="npd = $event" placeholder="Date {{i + 2}}" formControlName="next_payment_date_{{i+2}}" id="next_payment_date_{{i+2}}">
          <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="'next_payment' + i + 2"></button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker #next_payment_2></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the actual behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in html attribute using angula2 data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010986/error-in-html-attribute-using-angula2-data-binding)

Comment: why can't you just `let i = index + 2`???

Comment: @Fill, have you found the solution?

Comment: @Vega I think he haven't

Comment: @Fill I believe you'll need to wrap i + 2 in parenthesis. you're values are becoming 'next_payment02' because i + 2 is not in parenthesis. But if you are gonna use i + 2 everywhere in the ngFor iteration I would use cgTag's solution

Answer (score 0):

You could define a child component for the control and pass the i value as attribute. That way you can still use the local template variable #next_payment, and reference it for [mdDatepicker], [mdDatepickerToggle].

**HTML**

**patent component:**

```
  <div *ngFor="let payment of productForm.controls.next_payment.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <span>Payment {{i+2}}</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" 
               *ngIf="productForm.controls.next_payment.controls.length > 1" 
               (click)="removeNextPayment(index)"></span>
      </div>
      <my-payement-component [index]=i+2><my-payement-component>
  </div>
```

**child component:**

```
<div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="index">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="next_payment" [ngModel]="npd | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="npd = $event" placeholder="Date {{index}}"
                formControlName="next_payment_date" id="next_payment_date">
            <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="next_payment"></button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker #next_payment></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

**child component**

```
.....
@Input() index: number;
```

I wasn't able to test this code but I hope you get the idea

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6764A3JA5qzZpCcBqAP0?p=preview)**

Comment: I think `mdDatepickerToggle` directive should take instance of `MdDatePicker`(`#next_payment_2`) but you pass string to it

Comment: Sorry i didn't have enough time. I think we do not need `i + 2` here at all

Comment: Thank you @yurzui  so much for the reply and the time :)  The only place it's needed in the actual code as it is is here : 'placeholder="Date {{index}}"', but the OP may need it for other purposes that he would add afterwards?

Comment: Yeah, i agree, @Fill could be more polite and give us more information. I personally prefer prepared plunker :)